# text-view slides out of row-item of list-view android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am working on a project in which there is class which extends List View. In a get-view method  there is linear-layout in which i am adding some text view on few position till this it works fine but when i starts scrolling of list-view, text-view start **Sliding Out** of row item and comes on random position and multiple times. How i can fix this problem?

Inside a get-view method i am using following code to add text-view

```
                        TableRow.LayoutParams paramsExample = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0);
                        paramsExample.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
                        TextView tv = new TextView(activity);
                        tv.setLayoutParams(paramsExample);
                        tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        tv.setMaxLines(1);
                        tv.setTextSize(FontClass.fontSize);
                        tv.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);
                        tv.setText(eventList.get(i).getEventTitle() + "");
                        l.addView(tv);
```

adapter code...

```
private class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
        private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;
        private static final int TYPE_MAX_COUNT = TYPE_SEPARATOR + 1;

        private ArrayList<String> mDataDate = new ArrayList<String>();
        private ArrayList<String> mDataMonth = new ArrayList<String>();
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        private TreeSet<Integer> mSeparatorsSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();

        // String Text,UpperText;

        public MyCustomAdapter() {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        public void addItem(final String item1, final String item2) {
            mDataDate.add(item1);
            mDataMonth.add(item2);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void addSeparatorItem(final String item1, final String item2) {
            mDataDate.add(item1);
            mDataMonth.add(item2);
            // save separator position
            mSeparatorsSet.add(mDataDate.size() - 1);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return mSeparatorsSet.contains(position) ? TYPE_SEPARATOR
                    : TYPE_ITEM;
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return TYPE_MAX_COUNT;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mDataDate.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int position) {
            return mDataDate.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            int type = getItemViewType(position);
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                switch (type) {
                case TYPE_ITEM:
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item3, null);
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.textView = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.text);

                    holder.textViewR = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.txtData);


                    holder.textView.setTextSize(15);
                    holder.textViewR.setTextSize(25);

                    holder.imageViewHoliday = (ImageView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.imageViewHoliday);

                    Typeface ttf = Typeface
                            .createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(),
                                    "fonts/dk_crayon_crumble.ttf");
                    holder.textView.setTypeface(ttf);

                    // TODO: For Set View Line Programattically
                    holder.layout = (LinearLayout) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.ll);
                    View v = new View(getContext());
                    v.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(1,
                            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
                    v.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000);


                    holder.layout.addView(v);
                    holder.layoutRight = (LinearLayout) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.linearRight);
                    holder.textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#828282"));
                    break;

                case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item4, null);
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.textView = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.textSeparator);
                    holder.textViewR = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.txtData);
                    holder.layout = (LinearLayout) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.linearlayoutSeperator);
                    holder.imageViewHoliday = (ImageView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.imageViewHoliday);

                    Typeface ttfSeparator = Typeface
                            .createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(),
                                    "fonts/dk_crayon_crumble.ttf");
                    holder.textView.setTypeface(ttfSeparator);

                    holder.textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#111111"));
                    holder.layoutRight = (LinearLayout) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.linearRight);
                    break;
                }
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.textView.setText(mDataDate.get(position));

            // TODO TEXT SIZE CHANGING
            holder.textView.setTextSize(25);

            if (TYPE_ITEM == getItemViewType(position)) {
                // holder.textView.setTextSize(35);
                SharedPreferences sharePer = getContext().getSharedPreferences("SettingFontSizeMode", 0);

                String textSize = sharePer.getString("SettingFontSizeValue", "Medium");

                if(textSize.equals("Small"))
                {
                    FontClass.fontSize = 14;
                }

                if(textSize.equals("Medium"))
                {
                    FontClass.fontSize = 18;
                }
                if(textSize.equals("Large"))
                {
                    FontClass.fontSize = 22;
                }

                holder.textViewR.setTextSize(FontClass.fontSize);
            }

            // Holiday set work
            String Date = dayReplacement(mDataDate.get(position).replace("\n",""))+ " , " + mDataMonth.get(position);
            String[] str = Date.toString().split(" ");
            Holiday_Value = str[0] + " " + str[3].substring(0, 3);
            setHolidayList(Holiday_Value, holder.textViewR,holder.imageViewHoliday);
            // End of Holiday set work

            // Existing event set work
            String readEventDate = dayReplacement(mDataDate.get(position).replace("\n", "")) + " , " + mDataMonth.get(position);
            Log.i("position :", ""+position+" string : "+readEventDate);


            setReadCalendarEvents(readEventDate, holder.layoutRight, 0 );
            // End of Existing event set work

            holder.textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {
                        String Date = dayReplacement(mDataDate.get(position)
                                .replace("\n", ""))
                                + " , "
                                + mDataMonth.get(position);
                        eventSetDialog(Date);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            holder.layoutRight.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String Date = dayReplacement(mDataDate.get(position)
                            .replace("\n", ""))
                            + " , "
                            + mDataMonth.get(position);
                    eventSetDialog(Date);
                }
            });
            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

setReadEventCalendar code...

```
public void setReadCalendarEvents(String date, LinearLayout l, int count) {
        String[] passingDate = date.split(" ");

        if (passingDate[0].equals("") || passingDate[1] == ",") 
        {


        } 
        else {
            d = Integer.parseInt(passingDate[0]);
            m = 0;
            if (passingDate[3].equals("January")) {
                m = 0;
            } else if (passingDate[3].equals("February")) {
                m = 1;
            } else if (passingDate[3].equals("March")) {
                m = 2;
            } else if (passingDate[3].equals("April")) {
                m = 3;
            } else if (passingDate[3].equals("May")) {
                m = 4;
            } else if (passingDate[3].equals("June")) {
                m = 5;
            } else if (passingDate[3].equals("July")) {
                m = 6;
            } else if (passingDate[3].equals("August")) {
                m = 7;
            } else if (passingDate[3].equals("September")) {
                m = 8;
            } else if (passingDate[3].equals("October")) {
                m = 9;
            } else if (passingDate[3].equals("November")) {
                m = 10;
            } else if (passingDate[3].equals("December")) {
                m = 11;
            }

            y = Integer.parseInt(passingDate[4]);

            for (int i = 0; i < eventList.size(); i++) 
            {
                String[] str = eventList.get(i).getEventStartDate().split(" ");

                int aaSize = eventList.size();

                String comStr;
                if(m<9)
                {
                    if(d<10)
                    {
                        comStr = y+"-0"+(m+1)+"-0"+d;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        comStr = y+"-0"+(m+1)+"-"+d;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(d<10)
                    {

                        comStr = y+"-"+(m+1)+"-0"+d;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        comStr = y+"-"+(m+1)+"-"+d;
                    }

                }


                if (comStr.equals(str[0])) {
                    if (count < 6) {
                        count++;
                        TableRow.LayoutParams paramsExample = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0);
                        paramsExample.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
                        TextView tv = new TextView(activity);
                        tv.setLayoutParams(paramsExample);
                        tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        if(count == 0)
                        {
                            tv.setId(R.id.text1);
                        }
                        else if (count == 1)
                        {
                            tv.setId(R.id.text2);
                        }
                        tv.setMaxLines(1);
                        tv.setTextSize(FontClass.fontSize);
                        tv.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);
                        tv.setText(eventList.get(i).getEventTitle() + "");
                        l.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        l.addView(tv);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Whether you checked for the view is null condition???

Answer (score 1):

The thing with adapter based views is that they recycle their views. I would recommend to just add the extra `TextView` to xml and set it's visibility in `getView`method. This way the list can normally recycle it's views and doesn't get messed up.

If cannot use xml, create `ids.xml` in values folder. Assign an id to the dynamically created `TextView` so you can get the pointer to it. Only add the extra `TextView` once to the `TableLayout` and remember to update it's visibility in `getView` method.

Comment: due to my project requirement i can't take xml textview , i have to generate it programmatically,  thanks

Comment: Okay so in setReadCalendarEvents you should check if l already has view with id text1 or text2, get the pointer and update text, else hide the view. Now the code is adding the TextView when it can already exist.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44386/discussion-between-crazy-and-niko)